Ktor FormItem.value is not filtering out boundary element under high load
Hei, we are using Ktor with Netty configuration. Under low load on the server and in test environment everything working OK. In prod when load goes up we are experiencing for very few messages 5-6 per 60000 that the boundary element of a Multipart message is not filtered out when FormItem.value is invoked so it is returned appended to the payload. F.ex.
base64string0hlYWQ+
------=District_9_***********16588661--

We are using Ktor version 2.3.8
The code fragment reading the multipart message looks like this:
   val allParts = mutableListOf<PartData>().apply {
                this@receiveEbmsDokument.receiveMultipart().forEachPart {
                    if (it is PartData.FileItem) it.streamProvider.invoke()
                    if (it is PartData.FormItem) it.value
                    this.add(it)
                    it.dispose.invoke()
                }
            }

I have verified the top level Content-Type header and teh boundary is set correctly there and obviously it is also parsed if we dont count the end boundary element.
Is there any problem with the way we are reading the multipart elements, or is there a known bug in ktor ?

It seems like a concurrent bug in Ktor. Are you able to reproduce the issue in a local environment?

@AlekseiTirman no, it needs high load. I am currently writing a retry logic to check if the second execution will succeed. I will post results in an hour or so. The bug does not happen super often. But from what I see I am 99% convinced the retry will succeed. I alread checked the ending of the multipart message for illegal characters and double boundary ending all looks good. Also I am 99% certain that the client is also performing retry on this messages otherwise we would have heard.

@AlekseiTirman Now it is confirmed. The retry is succeeding. Looks like a Ktor bug. Should I verify it with latest Ktor?

Yes, please do.

@AlekseiTirman Just tested. No difference, bug still there.

@AlekseiTirman hei, can we conclude it is a big and can we expect it to be fixed? Are you able to locate it?

Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce it.

@AlekseiTirman what about the way i am reading the multipart request. Anything strange in it ?

It's okay, in my opinion, although you can try using the val allParts = call.receiveMultipart().readAllParts().forEach {...} call instead.

@AlekseiTirman This fragment was written so because ktor had a bug in the previous version on readAllParts(it was blocking) and this is a sort Of workaround for the previous big.  I upgraded ktor version to 12 an i recieved even more failures on the client side to be honest. I have not investigated further as i am on holiday. But my impression so far has been that ktor is a bit fragile with regards Of its Multipart functionality.

@AlekseiTirman is ktor using a softref or something like that that may be disposed earlier than it should with regards Of FormItem ?

Oh yeah, you should read the body of the FileItem part before closing it. Can you tell me where you use the result of the it.streamProvider.invoke()?

@AlekseiTirman after the invokation Of Datapart.dispose() but my issue has manifested on FormItem not on FileItem. But nevertheless what you Are saying is that dispose should not happen before the data is used. I thought data is cached in the datapart. But my problem is currently manifesting at FormItem.
